# Is a C-style cast identical to a function-style cast?

Tags: c++, casting

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/332086/480982) to the question "When should static_cast, dynamic_cast, const_cast and reinterpret_cast be used?":

> C-style cast and function-style cast are casts using `(type)object` or `type(object)`, respectively.

It then begins to list the behavior of the C-style cast, but never tells whether the function-style cast is identical or not.

I'm asking because Resharper for C++ warns me in case of C-style casts but does not warn me in case of function-style casts:

[image: Resharper screenshot]

In what way is the the function-style case different from the C-style cast? Or, if they are identical, is it a bug in Resharper and it should emit a warning, too? Is `int(d)` safe to use? It looks much simpler than the suggested `static_cast<int>(d);`.

Comment: Note that the two casts of `d` are rather different statements. One is an initialisation, the other an assignment. You should really compare `int i = int(d); int j = (int)d;` or `int i; i = int(d); i = (int)d;`

Comment: @Caleth: wouldn't the compiler optimize both ways into the same result?

Comment: In the case of `int`s? yes. In general? no. But my point is that there are *different language rules* about declarations and assignments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't have a quote from the standard, but cppreference is usually good enough.

[Explicit type conversion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast)

> The functional cast expression consists of a simple type specifier or a typedef specifier (in other words, a single-word type name: `unsigned int(expression)` or `int*(expression)` are not valid), followed by a single expression in parentheses. **This cast expression is exactly equivalent to the corresponding C-style cast expression.**

As for Resharper, it's possible that to it *C++ cast* includes a functional cast, as that is only valid in C++.

The answer you linked in your question explains how safe a functional cast is. In your case `int(d)` should be equivalent to `static_cast<int>(d)`. But in general a C-style or functional cast are unsafe as they can be equivalent to `reinterpret_cast` in certain situations, e.g. `(double*)some_int_ptr`.

Comment: "no cast is required anyway"? If I don't use a cast, the compiler emits warning C4244

Comment: Apologies. With the compiler I use (gcc) you have to explicitly ask for it to warn about this (`-Wconversion` for those interested). Update my answer.